# Connection issues to MySQL 5.5

Tags: mysql

I am trying to connect to an appliance that has a mySQL database running on it.
Let us call the appliance `APPLIANCE1`.
I am trying to connect to the database from SERVER1. SERVER1 has mySQL installed on it.

The command is simple enough:

```
mysql.exe --host=APPLIANCE --user=name --password=secret
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'name'@'SERVER1' (using password: YES)
```

Can anyone shine a light on why it keeps returning the following value: `name@SERVER1`. Is it not supposed to replace `SERVER1` with the host you are trying to connect to?

Much appreciated.

Comment: That's the host of 'user' which you need to [grant access http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html] to.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's the host you're connecting from.  This allows administrators to allow specific users to only login from specific hosts.